# The Police Took a Wonderful Taxi to Oz

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, symbols

[image: The Police Took a Wonderful Taxi to Oz]

Clues: [contextual images]
T [scissors] [hand shape] ?
[cylindrical contoured container]
$\sqrt{(m_{_0}c²) ² + (pc) ²}$

Instructions:

Name That Duo


_ _ _ _ _ _ D _ _ _ _ _

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm missing a few of the clues, but I'm quite confident the duo is:

> Bert and Ernie

The clues which support this:

> The jar looks like it could be an Urn, and the equation as identified by @Vicky equates to E. Add these together and you get Urn-e (Ernie).
>
>  The film It's A Wonderful Life has a Bert and Ernie combo. Ernie was a Taxi Driver and Bert a policeman. Combining this with Frank Oz, the original performer of Bert (the muppet from Sesame Street), goes a long way to explain the title.

I haven't deciphered the meaning of the `T [scissors] [hand shape] ?` section though.

OP Edit:

> The T - Scissors - Hand spells the name "Tim". Scissors = I, and the hand is the sign language symbol for the letter "M". The question mark at the end signifies that we are looking for something other than the name "Tim". The scissors and hand sign hint toward Tim "Burton" (Edward Scissorhands). This brings the clues to read "Burton Urn E" = Bert and Ernie

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer...

The equation represents

> Einstein's energy triangle so equates to E

The cylindrical container looks like a

> Hu jar (burial jar)

The hand shape looks like

> The ASL M shape

Comment: I think that the title speak about The police group the strange think is how he use the capital letter